# Calculating the joint distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Hey I am studying for a test tomorrow and need help with the following:

Given the r.v.'s $X_1$ ~ $N(0,1)$ and $X_2$ ~ $F_2(x_2) = \frac{1}{1-\exp(-x_2)}$ and the distribution function of $(X_1, X_2)$ given by

$$ F(x_1, x_2) = \frac{\Phi(x_1)}{1-\exp(-x_2)}\exp\Big[ \frac{1}{2} (\ln \Phi(x_1)) \ln(1-\exp(-x_2)) \Big] .$$ Furthermore let $Y_1 = \ln X_1$ and $Y_2 = 2X_2$, what is the distribution function of $(Y_1, Y_2)$?

Comment: Is it possible, that there is a typo in the exercise? I don't think that $F_2$ (calculated by $F_2 (x_2) = \lim_{x_1 \rightarrow \infty} F(x_1, x_2)$) is a distribution function. Probably there should be a plus in the denominator..?

Comment: $$F_{(Y_1,Y_2)}(y_1,y_2)=P(Y_1\leqslant y_1,Y_2\leqslant y_2)=P(X_1\leqslant e^{y_1},X_2\leqslant \tfrac12y_2)=F_{(X_1,X_2)}(e^{y_1},\tfrac12y_2)$$

Comment: Note however that if $X$ is normal then $Y=\ln X$ is undefined since $P(X<0)\ne0$. So, there is more than one problem in your question...